# Jenkins Master: Updating plugin data fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

On my Jenkins Master, versio 2.203, when I'm trying to update the plugins, I have this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found.
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:207)
at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:98)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:429)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:625)
```

I have tried the option `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS ="(..) -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"` but didn't work.

Any idea what I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I have. 

I have to remove the -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false option from my Jenkins Java Options. After that I can upgrade the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` from the Jenkins Java options fixed it for me. On Ubuntu, I went to the `etc/default/jenkins` file, located `JAVA_ARGS` and removed `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` from this line. You need to reboot the mahcine after that for the new settings to get in effect before you try to update the plugins again on Jenkins.